# Hibernate createCriteria list() return identical objects

Tags: hibernate, createcriteria

can you help me with the code below. I'm querying Hibernate and the number of objects  in the list
returned corresponds to the number of rows in my table. But it seems that every object in the list is identical. Indeed the following line prints the same user while in the table is different.

```
 System.out.println("p"+mo.getUser());
```

here is my code

```
List<MyObject> lp = (List<MyObject>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyObject.class).list();

         for (MyObject mo: lp) {

              System.out.println("p"+mo.getUser());
          }
```

Do you know what could cause this behaviour?
It's probably something stupid but I cannot find a solution.
Thanks

MyObject code:

```
package soc.entities;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
/**
 * Part generated by hbm2java
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="Part")
public class MyObcejet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String user

    public Part() {
    }




    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you please post the `MyObject` entity?

Comment: I've added the MyObject entity too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following line to avoid duplicate objects

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: I've tried this but with no luck. I have tried other tables and got the same behaviour. Thanks

Comment: Another thing I can add is that objects return have their default values (so for example id=0 and user is null)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue. Actually MyObject instance variables didn't correspond to my table column names. Thanks!